# Using __call__ method of a class as a input to Numpy curve_fit

Tags: python, class, numpy, call, curve-fitting

I would like to use a `__call__` method of a class as a input to a Numpy curve_fit function due to my rather elaborate function and data preparation process (fitting analytical model data to some measurements). It works just fine by defining a function, but I can't get it to work with classes.

To recreate my problem you can run:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#WORKS:
#def goal(x,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5):
#    y=a1*x**4*np.sin(x)+a2*x**3+a3*x**2+a4*x+a5
#    return y

# DOES NOT WORK:
class func():
    def __call__(self,x,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5):
        y=a1*x**4*np.sin(x)+a2*x**3+a3*x**2+a4*x+a5
        return y    

goal=func()

#data prepraration ***********
xdata=np.linspace(0,50,100)
ydata=goal(xdata,-2.1,-3.5,6.6,-1,2)
# ****************************

popt, pcov = curve_fit(goal, xdata, ydata)
print 'optimial parameters',popt
print 'The estimated covariance of optimial parameters',pcov
```

The error i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...some path...\test_minimizacija.py", line 35, in <module>
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(goal, xdata, ydata)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 412, in curve_fit
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(f)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\inspect.py", line 803, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('arg is not a Python function')
TypeError: arg is not a Python function
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: In my opinion, this is an example of a very nice StackOverflow question.  The question is outlined clearly, demonstrated with minimal code which can reproduce the problem.  The traceback is included.  Nicely done.  I hope more people upvote this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy (although, not pretty), just change it to:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(goal.__call__, xdata, ydata)
```

It's interesting that numpy forces you to pass a function object to `curve_fit` rather than an arbitrary callable ...

quickly inspecting the source for `curve_fit`, it appears that another workaround might be:

```
popt,pcov = curve_fit(goal, xdata, ydata, p0=[1]*5)
```

Here, `p0` is the initial guess for the fit parameters.  The problem appears to be that `scipy` inspects the arguments to the function so that it knows how many parameters to use if you don't actually provide parameters as an initial guess.  Here, since we have 5 parameters, my initial guess is a list of all ones of length 5.  (`scipy` defaults to using ones if you don't provide a guess also).

Comment: I’m not sure if `goal.__call__` will work, since the function is actually a method and has an extra parameter (`self`).

Comment: @poke -- Give it a try, it works just fine.  `goal.__call__` is the instance method which is a function that wraps around `func.__call__` and inserts the instance in the proper location when it calls `func.__call__`.

Comment: Okay, I’m going to trust you on that, as I don’t have numpy atm to test it myself. It’s just that `inspect.getargspec` still reports the `self` parameter for `goal.__call__`.

Comment: @poke -- Yeah.  But if you print the type, it still is of type `instancemethod` which means that it will get the first argument passed to it correctly by python's magic :)  We do the same thing in `Tkinter` all the time with callbacks -- `self.button = tk.Button(master,text="foo",command=self.method)`

Comment: @poke -- I'm starting to wonder if you're correct on this one.  My answer returns *something*, but I don't actually know if it's correct.  This is a bit strange -- looking at the traceback, it appears that numpy is trying to use the output of `getargspec` which makes me wonder if it's actually doing this correctly or not... Time for more testing.

Comment: @poke -- Yeah, numpy still gets it right (as I had hoped).  Comparison with the pure function that OP says is correct shows that they yield the same answer.  Note that if you change the first argument's name from `self` to `fooself` in `__call__`, it breaks.  Apparently numpy is relying heavily on that convention in this instance.  :).  Very interesting indeed.  Thanks for pointing that out and motivating me to dig a little deeper on this one.  (I didn't realize numpy was inspecting the function until pretty late in the game here -- I would have never realized it if not for your comment).

Comment: Good to know then, and thanks for doing further investigations :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers but the recomended solution does not work. I tried something similar myself. If i use goal.__call__ then i get (short version): TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 7 arguments (8 given)

Comment: @MihaPirnat -- interesting.  That's what I get if I use `fooself` as the name of the first argument to `func.__call__`.  What version of scipy are you using (`print scipy.__version__`)?  I have `0.11.0`

Comment: @MihaPirnat -- See my update, perhaps that version will work for you?

Comment: @MihaPirnat -- Great!  For posterity, could you post what version of scipy you're using?  I'm curious if my first answer didn't work out because my scipy is newer (or older) than yours.

Comment: I guess i have an older one, the print produced: 0.9.0